# Task Scheduling\Cron Jobs running Server

Tags: gratis, automation, task-management

I have over 100 Linux\Win servers and a few dozens of Tasks and Cron Jobs scattered around. I think it's time for a centralized system that will be able to run both remote Powershell scripts and Bash\Python. My only requirements are that it's free and has some form of a reporting feature.

Comment: I have not used it myself, but did you have a look at Jenkins (https://jenkins.io/)

Comment: I have heard it's absolutely terrible though.

Comment: I don't think Jenkins is the right tool. Ain't it more a build environment / continuous integration tool for software developers? But @gilfalko, maybe you can add the information to your question that you have tried it and you don't like it.

Comment: @gifalko Can you elaborate on "it's absolutely terrible though"?

Comment: Jenkins *_could_* be used, but it seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
eventually I found a solution capable of doing everything I wanted though it costs a single payoff of 500 dollars.
Google VisualCron.
It's a centrazlied tasks running server for Windows that looks and works great!

Answer (score 0):

[GRR](https://github.com/google/grr) possibly with [PowerGRR](https://github.com/swisscom/PowerGRR) sounds like just what you need:

- Python based, *(both Server and Remote Clients)*
- Cross Platform *(Windows, Linux & OS-X)*
- Search and download capabilities for files and the Windows registry.
- Detailed monitoring of client CPU, memory, IO usage and self-imposed limits.
- Remote power shell with PowerGRR

Free, *both Gratis & Open Source*, & oodles of reporting features.

Answer (score 0):

[Rundeck](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck) allows you to schedule and execute jobs defined in different languages. You can also tag your servers to have a more fine-grained control on execution.